# How to group by a math calculation in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to learning SQL and have a database that has three columns:

id (text),

source(text),

lastTime (timezone with timestamp)

I want to create a table that is grouped by the source and the total number of rows per source that have a lastTime of under 5 hours.

My current query is this:

```
SELECT
  source,
  EXTRACT(epoch FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  - lasttime) / 3600)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY source, lasttime
```

This obviously gives me a table that has multiple rows for the same source, and does not handle the < 5 hours bit. How can I change my query to handle these changes?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What's the database? Sybase, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: Apologies, I am new to StackOverflow. I am using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your question, you wanted counts per source with a condition. Unless I am missing something, I think you need

```
select source, count(*)
from mytable
where extract(epoch from (current_timestamp- lasttime) / 3600) < 5
group by source;
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a time range in the where clause? Like 2 < extract(epoch from (current_timestamp- lasttime) / 3600) < 5?

Comment: @SamanthaH. Instead of `< 5` you can do `between 3 and 4`. Note that `between` is an inclusive operator so it will include both 3 and 4. But if you are dealing with that diff in decimals, I would use `where extract ... >2 and extract.... <5`

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Many databases support column aliases in the `group by`, so you can do:

```
SELECT source,
       EXTRACT(epoch FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  - lasttime) / 3600) as diff
FROM mytable
GROUP BY source, diff;
```

In those that do not (which is actually the SQL standard), you can repeat the expression:

```
SELECT source,
       EXTRACT(epoch FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  - lasttime) / 3600) as diff
FROM mytable
GROUP BY source, EXTRACT(epoch FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  - lasttime) / 3600);
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! How would you specify diff to be less than 5?